# Conversion from Celsius to Fahrenheit is returning 0.00

Tags: c

I am writting a C program to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa. When I convert from F to C it runs just fine. But when I try to convert from C to F I always get 0.00 as my returned value.
Here is my code.

```
int main (void)
{

int fahrenheit;
double celsius;
int convert;

while (celsius != 0 || fahrenheit != 32) {
    printf("Type 1 if you would like to convert to celsius.\n");
    printf("Type 2 if you would like to convert to fahrenheit.\n");
    scanf("%d", &convert);
    printf("\n");

    if(convert == 1){
        printf("Enter the temperature in degrees fahrenheit:\n");
        scanf("%d", &fahrenheit);
        celsius = (5.0/9.0) * (fahrenheit-32);
        printf ("The converted temperature is %.2f\n", celsius);
        printf ("\n");
        }
    else{
        printf("Enter the temperature in degrees celsius:\n");
        scanf("%d", &celsius);
        fahrenheit = (1.8*celsius) + 32;
        printf ("The converted temperature is %.2f\n", fahrenheit);
        printf ("\n");
        }
    }
return 0;

}
```

Comment: always initalize local variables.

Comment: You made `fahrenheit` an `int`, but you print is as floating point.

Comment: Also, you are using `"%d"` to read `celsius` when it is of type `double`. Use `"%lf"`.

Comment: `double celsius; ... scanf("%d", &celsius);` should warn during compilation of the mis-match format specifier - `"%lf"`.  Either enable all warnings or get a better compiler.

Comment: @chux s/should/could/  There are compilers that issue diagnostic messages for scanf/printf argument mismatch, but it is not required for any compiler. `GCC` had not been tagged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
scanf("%d", &celsius);
...
printf ("The converted temperature is %.2f\n", fahrenheit);
```

You declared `fahrenheit` as an `int` and `celsius` as a `double`, so the `%f` and `%d` format specifiers should be switched.

```
scanf("%lf", &celsius);
...
printf ("The converted temperature is %d\n", fahrenheit);
```

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest making both celsius and integers floats instead of ints, since the conversion won't result in an integer in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

in your code,

```
printf ("The converted temperature is %.2f\n", fahrenheit);
```

you're trying to print one `int` with a format specifier of `%f`. Not a defined behavior.

Then again

```
scanf("%d", &celsius);
```

Should be

```
scanf("%f", &celsius);  //c89 and above
```

or

```
scanf("%lf", &celsius); //c99 and above
```

Also, initialize the local variable yourself. They aren't *auto* initialized. Otherwise, don't be surprised if sometimes [less likely but not impossible]

```
while (celsius != 0 || fahrenheit != 32)
```

fails in the first iteration itself.